# What does 'time machine' imply in the context?

Tags: word-meaning

What does *time machine* suggest? It must not be a literal meaning, 'a machine capable of transporting a person backward or forward in time' in science fiction, so if I infer it in the passage, I guess it is a kind of machine that makes time go faster or slower. Do you agree?

> The most surreal consequence of melting ice and rising seas is that
> together they are a kind of ***time machine***, so real that they are
> altering the length of our days: It works like this: As the glaciers
> melt and the seas rise, gravity forces more water toward the equator.
> This changes the shape of the Earth ever so slightly, making it fatter
> around the middle, which in turns slows the rotation of the planet
> similarly to the way a ballet dancer slows her spin by spreading out
> her arms. The slowdown isn’t much, just a few thousandths of a second
> each year, but like the barely noticeable jump of rising seas every
> year, it adds up. When dinosaurs roamed the Earth, a day lasted only
> about twenty-three hours.
> [The Water Will Com](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=oXOZDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT58&lpg=PT58&dq=As%20the%20glaciers%20melt%20and%20the%20seas%20rise,%20gravity%20forces%20more%20water%20toward%20the%20equator.%20This%20changes%20the%20shape%20of%20the%20Earth%20ever%20so%20slightly,%20making%20it%20fatter%20around%20the%20middle,%20which%20in%20turns%20slows%20the%20rotation%20of%20the%20planet%20similarly%20to%20the%20way%20a%20ballet%20dancer%20slows%20her%20spin%20by%20spreading%20out%20her%20arms.&source=bl&ots=hHqUDYBZWE&sig=ACfU3U2fH7GwELx94V7PjstCs_gHv87ZXg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi629_i2bSCAxXC0mEKHQxnAB8Q6AF6BAghEAM#v=onepage&q=As%20the%20glaciers%20melt%20and%20the%20seas%20rise%2C%20gravity%20forces%20more%20water%20toward%20the%20equator.%20This%20changes%20the%20shape%20of%20the%20Earth%20ever%20so%20slightly%2C%20making%20it%20fatter%20around%20the%20middle%2C%20which%20in%20turns%20slows%20the%20rotation%20of%20the%20planet%20similarly%20to%20the%20way%20a%20ballet%20dancer%20slows%20her%20spin%20by%20spreading%20out%20her%20arms.&f=false)

Comment: It's a time-machine only in the sense that it has an impact on the absolute length of the earth day. Did you read the paragraph, or just stop when you got to the words "time machine"?

Comment: I don't think @TimR was making fun, just asking whether you had read the explanation of _the sense in which 'time machine' is being used here_.

Comment: Time machine is not a word used to describe anything other than a fictional item. The given answer is reaching. May be the question is well-suited for diffrerent SE and not ELL

Comment: Accusing people is not a good look on here, TUALL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The author is stretching the notion of "time machine" beyond the most common one. It's true that the primary idea people have of a "time machine" is "a device in speculative fiction that lets people travel to 'the past' or 'the future.'" But there have been works of speculative fiction that manipulate time in other ways. The author is here talking about a day becoming longer, and many works have explored the idea of freezing time or speeding or slowing its passage.
2. Of course it's still partly just a metaphor or a figure of speech, since a change in Earth's rotational speed doesn't actually impact the absolute passage of time (like in the movie where Superman goes back in time by reversing the Earth's rotation). It just changes the *amount* of time that a rotation occupies. But it's still an arresting and effective figure of speech.

Comment: Oh, Andy, I had no idea of a time machine that manipulates time. I appreciate your perfect answer.

Comment: @TUALL If you like this answer, consider clicking the grey check mark beside it to indicate that it satisfies your question.